# Add anchor to existing url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, href, location-href

On a page I want to add a anchor after the existing URL after clicking on a link. So for example my URL in the page I am at the moment is www.google.nl and after clicking the link it needs to be www.google.nl/#anchor.
How can I do this?

**Second question:**

If I click a productlink (WooCommerce product grid) I want to prevent going to that page and have a function that gets the URL of the product and pass it into this function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a").click(function(){
        jQuery("#bestellen").load("dynamic URL here got from the product I clicked on");

    });
});
```

Comment: For your second question - why don't you just set the links to what you want them to be from the beginning? It sounds like you want to show one link but then take the user to a different place when they click.. which is a bit weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach an [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) click event with jQuery and change the `href` property with [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) like this:

```
$('a.my-selector').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prop('href','https://example.com');
});
```

Comment: Do you know a answer on my second question?

Comment: @JGR -  Instead of editing your post to ask an additional question, you should post a new question and let it get answered there.